# How can I make a table cell take no space?

Tags: html, css, fonts, css-tables

I have a complex tree-like table layout (few cells on the left, many on the right), and I want to make certain cells (and their rows) vanish completely (with Javascript, based on class).

`visibility:hidden` just makes the contents invisible, and setting the text-size and border of the cells makes them small, but I'm stuck with a few pixels left.  I've tried `line-height:0, padding:0 border-spacing:0`, but the cells are still taking up about two pixels, with another two pixels vertically between them.

Does someone have a list of the css attributes which have to be zero to get a cell to disappear completely?

Comment: [You shouldn't be using tables for layouts!](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6036/why-arent-we-supposed-to-use-table-in-a-design/6037#6037)

Comment: Do you want to try: table
{
border-collapse:collapse;
} just in case.

Comment: So you want to hide entire rows (hiding individual cells does not affect layout)?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [CSS display](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/display) property:

```
style="display: none;"
```

If that doesn't work wrap the content in a `<span>` and use it on that instead